# How to redirect to URL using SPRING BeanNameViewResolver

Tags: spring, redirect, model-view-controller

Is it possible to redirect to another URL inside Spring MVC controller while using BeanNameViewResolver? 
Perhaps in a way just escaping the bean name resolving?

This obviously only works with the UrlBasedViewResolver

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView postPage(HttpServletRequest req){
    return "redirect:http://localhost:9090/flowID";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public View postPage(HttpServletRequest req, Map<String, Object> model){
    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("http://localhost:9090/flowID");
    return redirectView;
}
```